# Flash Idle load images

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, lazy-loading, preload

I have a series of approximately 50 images each approximately 100kb each that needs to be loaded into flash. They cannot be loaded one by one because they need to be responsive to animations. I was thinking if maybe i can load like a certain amount of them initially so that preload time is less. Then just load the images when the user is interacting with the site and not using the images directly. Essentially what im trying to get at is secretly loading the images while the user is say "reading a single page", i could use that valuable time loading content (something like lazy-loading).

Thanks any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look at [LoaderMax](http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/) from greensock.

It gives you the ability to create a loading sequence. For instance, you could decide to load a certain number of images , then add more images to the loading sequence whenever you wish. You could also pause & resume loading which can be handy when you don't want the loading process to interfere with some other processes such as tween animations.

Answer (score 2):

[Bulk loader](http://code.google.com/p/bulk-loader/) is a good alternative.

It's a lot like LoaderMax, just different syntax.